# How do I correctly setup smooth scrolling when $('.nav a) is clicked on?

Tags: jquery, html

This is a one page site, with parent menu items anchored to sections in the content area. Everything is anchored and working correctly except the smooth scrolling.

How do I correctly setup the smooth scrolling when "$(.nav a)" is clicked on?

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var services = $('.services').offset().top;
  var locations = $('.locations').offset().top;
  var about = $('.about').offset().top;
  var contact = $('.contact').offset().top;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPos >= services && scrollPos < locations) {
      $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
      $('.wsite-nav-2 a').addClass('active');
    } else if (scrollPos >= locations && scrollPos < about) {
      $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
      $('.wsite-nav-3 a').addClass('active');
    } else if (scrollPos >= about && scrollPos < contact) {
      $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
      $('.wsite-nav-4 a').addClass('active');
    } else if (scrollPos >= contact) {
      $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
      $('.wsite-nav-5 a').addClass('active');
    } else if (scrollPos <= services) {
      $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
      $('.wsite-nav-1 a').addClass('active');
    }
  });

  $('.wsite-nav-1 a').addClass('active');

  $('.nav a').click(function() {
    $('.nav a, .wsite-nav-1 a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var target = $('.anchor-link').offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery( jQuery(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="wsite-nav-1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="wsite-nav-2"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li class="wsite-nav-3"><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
    <li class="wsite-nav-4"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="wsite-nav-5"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="anchor">
    <a name="A" class="anchor-link services"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="anchor">
    <a name="B" class="anchor-link locations"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="anchor">
    <a name="C" class="anchor-link about"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="anchor">
    <a name="D" class="anchor-link contact"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: make the value `500` bigger

Comment: @TemaniAfif No go, but thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

Your smooth scrolling code is perfect except that the href attributes of the `nav a` links are all `#` it should be `id` of the respective sections. I have updated my recent codepen again check  :) https://codepen.io/bb027/pen/VMQdXL

Comment: This almost works, but the smooth scrolling is slightly abrupt, but not as abrupt as if there were no smooth scrolling. I changed it to 1000, but no change in speed.

Comment: Which part of it is abrupt ? scrolling to the section or the menu highlighting ? and btw which browser are you checking in cause i increased the animate delay to 1500 it clearly is scrolling at its slowest compared to 400?

Comment: Once I click on $('.nav a'), the scrolling to the anchor links is slightly abrupt. I'm using Chrome. I'll try 1500 and see.

Comment: It should'nt even be a little abrupt may be there is some other js error check your console and see if there are any errors present before/after click event.

Comment: Just checked console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>. The error is in the jQuery.